# How to convert 8-digit hex to the equivalent 6-digit hex code in php?

Tags: php, colors, hex, transparency

I am trying to determine colors for my site's themes. A great way I've found to do so is to take a main 6-digit hex color and simply add opacity on to the end of the hex code to get a complimentary color. The problem I'm having is that any time the secondary (the 8-digit hex code) color is to be on top of the main color you can't see it. Is there any way in css or php to convert an 8-digit hex code to it's equivalent color in a normal 6-digit hex code.

For example, my main color and secondary colors are as follows:

```
#053d06
#053d0614
```

I could go into a color picker and grab the secondary color and manually code it that way, but I'm trying to do it programmatically. I have tried clemblanco's rgba2hex/hex2rgba code, but that seems to just translate it back to the main color instead of the equivalent secondary color. Any help is appreciated! Thank you.

ETA: More directly I want a hex color that is the same color as the 8-digit code put over a white background. Thank you.

Comment: What do you mean by "equivalent colour"? Do you mean the colour created when the semi-transparent colour is placed on top of a particular background? If so, what you're technically looking for is "alpha blending" - combining two (or more) colours using an "alpha" (transparency) channel.

Comment: @IMSoP I guess so, yes. The color it creates when put over the white background. I will look up "alpha blending". Thank you.

Comment: The convention here is to keep Questions and Answers strictly separate. It's perfectly acceptable to add an Answer to your own question, but you should *not* add answer information into the Question section of the page. It just fits better with the system that way. 

Comment: I will fix that, thank you for keeping me in check, haha

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLUTION: I ended up just adjusting the brightness of my main color instead of trying to convert an alpha hex to a non-alpha hex. Here is what I am using and it works great:

```
function adjustBrightness($hexCode, $adjustPercent) {
    $hexCode = ltrim($hexCode, '#');

    if (strlen($hexCode) == 3) {
        $hexCode = $hexCode[0] . $hexCode[0] . $hexCode[1] . $hexCode[1] . $hexCode[2] . $hexCode[2];
    }

    $hexCode = array_map('hexdec', str_split($hexCode, 2));

    foreach ($hexCode as & $color) {
        $adjustableLimit = $adjustPercent < 0 ? $color : 255 - $color;
        $adjustAmount = ceil($adjustableLimit * $adjustPercent);

        $color = str_pad(dechex($color + $adjustAmount), 2, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);
    }

    return '#' . implode($hexCode);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Directly getting the substring or dividing off the two hex digits `16**2 -> 256` could be a practical way to truncate 'em if that's all you're after

```php
php > $hex = "#053d0614";
php > echo substr($hex, 0, 7);
#053d06
php > echo '#'.substr('000000'.dechex(intdiv(hexdec($hex), 256)), -6);
#053d06
```

Comment: I'm not looking to truncate it - I'm looking to get the equivalent color that the 8-digit hex makes when put over a white background.